# Changing ActiveAdmin's select-type filter to not have the "any" option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter, activeadmin

How do I remove the "Any" option from a select-type filter?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a monkeypatch to disable it for all select filters. Stick it in `initializers/active_admin.rb`.

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Inputs
    class FilterSelectInput < ::Formtastic::Inputs::SelectInput

     def input_options
       super.merge(:include_blank => false)
     end
    end
  end
end
```